# Improve JavaScript regex to match content inside of tags with or without closing tag, excluding self

Tags: javascript, regex

> Preface: I'm aware about general consensus standing against using *regex* to parse HTML. Asking you in advance, please avoid any recommendations in this regard.

---

### Explanations.

I have the following regex

```
/<div class="panel-body">([^]*?)(<\/div>|$)/gi
```

It matches all content, including self, inside of the the `div` with class `.panel-body`

**Full match:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
</div>
```

.. it also matches content with no closing `div` tag.

**Full match:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
   Don't match after closing `div`...but match this and below in case closing `div` is removed.
   Line below 1
   Line below 2
   Line below 3
```

### Question.

How could I improve my regex to do the following:

1. Not include in the full match `<div class="panel-body">` and closing `</div>` (when there is closing `div` tag)
2. To do this straight (if possible) into the *full match* without using groups

[regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/EnojbS/1)

---

#### Edit 1:

The string doesn't start with `<div class="panel-body">`, it starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Webmin 1.851 on centos.centos (CentOS Linux 7.3.1611)</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<div class="panel-body">
```

* *Note:* It's never closed until the full load as it's progressive output.

#### Edit 2:

After posted answers, I made speed comparison tests. It's up to you, whose  solution would serve best for you.

[Speed-test Results](https://jsperf.com/match-vs-domparser-vs-indexof)

Comment: You can't omit the starting part, because this is only possible with lookbehinds which JS doesn't support. So your only option is `match(...)[1]`

Comment: @georg I thought that but wanted to double check. Then only option _1_ remains valid.

Comment: I understand you only want regex answers but using `DOM` can solve this  easily.

Comment: @anubhava Hi, regex guru! :) What do you mean by `using DOM` exactly?

Comment: I meant this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: I know what `DOM` is! ☺️ It's not easier, because the HTML is spit from progressive output and never complete until the final load.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/466738

Comment: Adam, thanks. I know it and read it. Did you see my preface? What I do for my project is special and can't be done otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `DOM` parser, that should with incomplete tags as well:

```js
function divContent(str) {
  // create a new dov container
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  // assign your HTML to div's innerHTML
  div.innerHTML = '<html>' + str + '</html>';

  // find an element by given className
  var el = div.getElementsByClassName("panel-body");
  
  // return found element's first innerHTML
  return (el.length > 0 ? el[el.length-1].innerHTML : "");
}

// extract text from a complete tag:
var html = `<div class="panel-body">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
</div>`;
console.log(divContent(html));

// extract text from an incomplete tag:
html = `<div class="panel-body">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
   Don't match after closing 'div'...but match this and below
   in case closing 'div' is removed.
   Line below 1
   Line below 2
   Line below 3`;   
console.log(divContent(html));

// OP'e edited HTML text
html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Webmin 1.851 on centos.centos (CentOS Linux 7.3.1611)</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<div class="panel-body">`;
console.log(divContent(html));
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hvsryuus/)

Comment: Is it faster than regex?

Comment: The size is constantly growing with each request. It's progressive output.

Comment: Then both regex or non-regex solutions will become slower after a certain point.

Comment: It doesn't start with this `<div>`. It starts as regular HTML5 page. Will your example work with the whole bunch of not closed `div` tags, not mentioning `body` and `html`?

Comment: Sorry, my friend. That is incorrect! Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div><div>` to your `divStr` var and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you. It goes beyond closing div. Here is the test data: https://pastebin.com/1jz2miuz

Comment: Yes, of course. HTML on the out side will always be valid.

Comment: It's great. `<pre>` tag is closed automatically in my example?

Comment: Yes, that is done by HTML parser used by DOM module. That shouldn't harm and in fact can be beneficial.

Comment: Yes `indexOf` is fastest but your problem of unclosed tags is best solved by `DOM`, so it is speed vs accuracy

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment yet so I will try an answer. How about non-capturing groups, You still have it in the full match, but your only entry in matches would be the content.  so index 0.

```
(?:<div class="panel-body">)([^]*?)(?:<\/div>|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/OJf1Rt/3

Comment: First non-capturing group is not needed

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a regexp? You could just look for the opening tag and optionally drop the closing tag, if present:

```
function parseContent(input) {
  var openingTag = '<div class="panel-body">';

  var i = input.indexOf(openingTag);
  if (i == -1) {
    return ""; // Or something else
  }

  var closingTag = '</div>';
  var closingTagLength = closingTag.length;
  var end = input.length - (input.slice(-closingTagLength) === closingTag ? closingTagLength : 0);

  return input.slice(i + openingTag.length, end);
}
```

---

EDIT:

If there can be text after the closing tag, then just use `indexOf` there too:

```
function parseContent(input) {
  var openingTag = '<div class="panel-body">';

  var i = input.indexOf(openingTag);
  if (i == -1) {
    return ""; // Or something else
  }

  var closingTag = '</div>';

  var endIndex = input.indexOf(closingTag, i);
  var end = (endIndex === -1 ? input.length : endIndex);

  return input.slice(i + openingTag.length, end);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting solution. I like it. Do you think `indexOf()` will be faster than `regex`?

Comment: However, it matches the text outside of the closing `div` tag. Have a look: https://pastebin.com/AwuCpFMe

Comment: Do you really need to worry about speed? The AJAX request will take so long the few milliseconds difference between the different parsing solutions will be negligible. Other than that, check my edit.

Comment: Actually it's much faster on progressive output. It's all about the possible amount of data that can go megabytes in theory. Example how it works. It's all SPA: https://rostovtsev.ru/pub/src/authentic/19.00-RC2/new_amazing_buffered_header_with_working_post_save_commands.webm

Comment: `.indexOf()` seems to be fastest. https://jsperf.com/match-vs-domparser-vs-indexof

Answer (score 1):

If **no tags**, you can use - all lines not start by < character

```
(^|\r|\n|\r\n)[^<]+
```

For **specific example** getting the first line with

```
\<[^div] ([^\r\n]*\n)+
```

If there are other lines after  you will need to put the last characters to end it:

```
\<[^div] ([^\r\n]*\n)+Line 3
```

Comment: It wouldn't work because it contains other tags there. I updated my question, adding other tag element to the container.

Comment: That is not correct regex101.com/r/ev7jd1/1 - it matches beyond `</div>` tag.

Comment: This is horrible, I'm sorry pal, no offence. You are not serious, I know! :) This time I'm downvoting.